# how to prevent Windows dual boot from changing BIOS boot priority

Tags: multi-boot, grub

I have dual boot running Windows and Endeavour OS, and it will usually boot nicely into GRUB and I have my 3 seconds or whatever to select Endeavour, my recovery partition, or Windows. However, each time I boot into Windows, it moves its own boot partition to the top of the BIOS priority list. Every time I want to switch back to Linux after playing some games, I have to go back and manually rearrange my drive boot order.

Is there a way to tell GRUB to keep itself on the top of the priority list regardless of where I boot to, or am I looking in the wrong place for a solution?